# repetitive task in R with a character string using sapply or a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, rstudio, lapply, sapply

I have the repetitive task of extracting parts of a list and saving them to a new variable name.

I can use `aaa_report <- original[["aaa"]]` and I have a new variable named `aaa_report` which is a the `aaa` section from the list variable `original`

Now I would like to automate this repetitive task:

`aaa_report <- original[["aaa"]]`

`bbb_report <- original[["bbb"]]`

`ccc_report <- original[["ccc"]]`

`...`

I have a separate "character" list variable named `dept` with all the names `dept <- c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "...")`

I try to use `sapply` and get this error.

```
sapply(dept, function(x) x"_report" <- original[[x]])
```

> Error: unexpected string constant in "sapply(dept, function(x)
>   x"_report""

I have tried all the `apply` family and a `for loop` with no luck.

```
for(x in dept){
  x"_report" <- original[[x]]
}
```

I am a beginner to R and programming in general, so any advice will be much help.

Comment: Why not just keep them in the list and reference them when needed? This seems like a more reasonable way to go. See gregor's answer on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) for a number of useful methods to run through named list elements.

Comment: I will use the pieces of the list later combined in a different way

Comment: If you really want to do this (keeping stuff in lists is nearly always best) use `get(paste0(x, "_report"))`

Comment: As stated by the 2 comments above, make a list a keep a list, it's way better.  And you may also want to look at the function `split` which will make it for you.  After, do all your analysis with `lapply` or `sapply`directly on your list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, use the `assign` function:

```
for(x in dept) assign(paste0(x, "_report"), original[[x]])
```

It would not work with the `apply` functions, since the assignment will be in the local environment of the `apply` function.

As stated in the comments, keeping everything in a list is always better.